# Can you disable new users being created with Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've used Parse.com for creating users and to log in, into my application. However I was wondering if there is some way I could disable new users being created up via the Parse.com website. I.e. when the Parse method is used to create the account I can set via the Parse website to not respond to the request or something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use class level permissions to restrict creation of new users. When viewing your parse app's dashboard online navigate to Users. Click on security. Then click the settings symbol to toggle advanced permisson. You can then deny your app permission to create new users. Please see https://www.parse.com/docs/data#security-classes

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cloud Code](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) and implement the *beforeSave* for **Parse.User**

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  /*if (!request.object.get("email")) {
    response.error("email is required for signup");
  } else {
    response.success();
  }*/
});
```